# Civil Case - Damages exceeding $250,0000.00 (sic)

Tags: civil-judgment

First, the number in the title is not a typo. This is from a civil case that reads:  "WHEREFORE Plaintiffs respectfully pray for the Judgement of this Court in their favor and against ######, for damages exceeding $250,0000.00 for post judgement interest at the rate of 9% per annum, for Plaintiff's costs in this matter, including reasonable attorney's fees, and for any such other and further relied as the Court may deem just and proper under the circumstances."

...updating to remove link to docket entry.

I understand the value is surely a typo.  Our attorney believes they likely meant $25,000.  But is this error important? I also tried asking on the Math stack exchange . . . to see if this is a "valid" number. A few responders said this is more of a legal matter.  Can the court make a judgement based on a request of a number that doesn't really seem valid?  As stated, are they asking for a judgement of value of something that doesn't exist (like a unicorn or mermaid, etc.) Thank you!

Comment: Looks rather more like they intended to ask for $250,000 than $25,000.

Comment: Please link to the docket entry that claims so

Comment: @Trish - here is the docket entry link.  I don't immediately see how to get to the Petition that lists that amount, but perhaps you'll know where to find it? Thank you!https://www.courts.mo.gov/cnet/cases/newHeader.do?inputVO.caseNumber=2322-CC00632&inputVO.courtId=CT22#docket

Comment: Link is defect.

Comment: @Trish the link is not defective, but the server is returning empty responses to certain IP address ranges.  A VPN with a US IP address will allow you to open it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The error is not important

It’s surely a mistake that will be clarified and corrected long before anyone enters a courtroom.